# PayPal Manager account - PayPal SDK/API Limited Access - Payflow Transparent Redirect

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I have a developer account and a manager account that I have been using to test PayPal Payments Advanced with Hosted Pages.  Now I would like to test PayPal Payments Pro with Transparent Redirect.

The process should be fairly simple but I'm getting "Error: Token is missing" even tho I'm supply the tokens.  So the first thing I'm wondering is in my manager account in the Service Summary the PayPal SDK/API is listed with Limited Access.  Is that a problem?  How do I get Full Access?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been told that to use transparent redirect you have to have a PayPal Payments Pro account.  So I created a new account on PayPal Manager and selected Payflow Pro during setup.  This doesn't fix the error I'm getting but it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decide if you are using Secure Token or not. If you are not using Secure token, make certain that you set Secure Token to no in your hosted pages. If you are using Secure Token then make certain to set secure token to yes. Below are the instructions for the hosted Checkout Pages:

Under Service Summary, click on Hosted Checkout Pages, then click on Setup, after that scroll down to the bottom of the page and change secure token to no if not using the feature or yes if you are using secure token, and then save changes.

Here is the Payflow Link Developer's Guide that has a reference to limited access accounts:
[Page 7 of Payflow Link Developer's Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowlink_guide.pdf)

Some older Payflow Link Accounts or account that were setup as new Payflow Link users have limited access to SDK/Apis. This means that if you have limited access you need to use the Payflow Link Developer's Guide rather than the Payflow Gateway Developer Guide. It is most likely related to using a Test Account verses a live account.

Comment: Thx but from what I've read that document does not apply to me.  Also I am using a test account with secure token.